# How to over ride property value in laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am trying to over ride the property value using a foreach loop.

Here is what I am trying

```
$runningLeagues = $this->getLeagueListing('running', $clubIds);
// chanage city
foreach($runningLeagues as $d){
    $d->club->city = $d->city;
}
return $runningLeagues;
```

But if I just return from the loop I get the correct result. So the below code works.

```
foreach($runningLeagues as $d){
    $d->club->city = $d->city;
    return $d; // it shows the overridden city. It works.
}
```

I have city property inside club object and outside object as well. I want to change the city inside the club object from the outside city property value.

It keeps the values same. It doesn't change.

**Update**

it seems it updates with the last item. So if last properties city is 'ss' it will add 'ss' in all the properties.

Any idea whats happening?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**First. Laravel collection `each()` method:**

```
$runningLeagues->each(function ($d) {
    $d->club->city = $d->city;
});
```

**Second. By collection index:**

```
foreach($runningLeagues as $k => $d) {
    $runningLeagues[$k]->club->city = $d->city;
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Laravel, but are you sure you need to do that? Check [this sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/summer-snowflake-oweo) out. Since items are objects, they should be iterated over "by reference" by default, at least that's what's happening in that snippet.